# How to display the last n lines of an updated log file on a webpage without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, websocket

I have created a Python application that emulates the `tail-f` command in UNIX, to display the last 10 logs of a logfile, currently my code detects the changes in a logfile and sends updates via wobsockets to the client and displays on the webpage without refreshing it.

Here's what my code does

1. when I run the server and client initially it displays the last 10 lines of a log file on the webpage.
2. when I update the logfile the 11th line is displayed too, if I updated it with n lines more it does display the n lines along with the first 10 lines that were initially displayed.

just for depicting, what I want my final output to look like, let's say I want to display the last 5 lines of a log file

my logfile looks something like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

on running the server and client my webpage displays this (the last 5 lines of the logpage)

```
3
4
5
6
7
```

so when I update the log file with a new entry let's say --> 8, my final output should be

```
4
5
6
7
8
```

this should happen without refreshing the page but for now it gets printed as

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Here is my `server.py` file

```
import time
import os.path
import asyncio
import logging
from collections import deque

import websockets
from ansi2html import Ansi2HTMLConverter

NUM_LINES = 10
HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = 15

conv = Ansi2HTMLConverter(inline=True)

async def view_log(websocket, path):
    try:
        file_path='log.log'
        tail=True

        i=0
        with open(file_path) as f:
            content = ''.join(deque(f, NUM_LINES))
            content = conv.convert(content, full=False)
            await websocket.send(content)

            if tail:
                last_heartbeat = time.time()
                while True:
                    content = f.read()
                    if content:
                        i+=1
                        content = conv.convert(content, full=False)
                        await websocket.send(content)
                    else:
                        await asyncio.sleep(1)

                    # heartbeat
                    #print(last_heartbeat)
                    if time.time() - last_heartbeat > HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL:
                        try:
                            await websocket.send('ping')
                            pong = await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), 5)
                            if pong != 'pong':
                                raise Exception()
                        except Exception:
                            raise Exception('Ping error')
                        else:
                            last_heartbeat = time.time()

            else:
                await websocket.close()

    except ValueError as e:
        try:
            await websocket.send(e)
            await websocket.close()
        except Exception:
            pass

        log_close(websocket, path, e)

    except Exception as e:
        log_close(websocket, path, e)

    else:
        log_close(websocket, path)


def log_close(websocket, path, exception=None):
    message = 'Closed, remote={}, path={}'.format(websocket.remote_address, path)
    if exception is not None:
        message += ', exception={}'.format(exception)
    logging.info(message)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--host', default='127.0.0.1')
    parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, default=8765)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    start_server = websockets.serve(view_log, args.host, args.port)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

here is my `demo.html` file where the O/P is displayed

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Logviewer Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre id="logs"></pre>
    <script>
      let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8765')
      ws.onmessage = (event) => {
        if (event.data === 'ping') {
          ws.send('pong')
          return
        }
        document.getElementById('logs').innerHTML += event.data
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

to run this you need to follow these steps in your command line

1. `python server.py --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8765`
2. `python -m http.server`
3. Open this on your webbrowser `http://localhost:8000/demo.html`

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved in the front end. To do so, you can create a function that takes the following steps:

1. Get element reference
2. Create a variable, assign it to our elements current text, and add our new log text to it, with a new line in between
3. Split our new string into an array, splitting at new lines ('\n')
4. Splice out all array elements that are not the last 5
5. Join the array back into a string with new lines separating each
6. Assign our new string to the elements innerText

The function will look like this:

```
function updateLog(newLog){
    let elem = document.getElementById('logs')
    let newText = elem.innerText + '\n' + newLog
    newText = newText.split('\n')
    newText.splice(0, newText.length-5)
    newText = newText.join('\n')
    elem.innerText = newText
}
```

Put that function inside your `<script>` section

Delete this line, as we are replacing it with our function call:

```
document.getElementById('logs').innerHTML += event.data
```

Then use the new function instead:

```
updateLog(event.data)
```